# starts / begins with multiple columns grepl/paste0

Tags: r

EDIT: I´v changed the question a little bit.

I want to check if AP or OP starts with the strings in S. If yes then mut=1.

```
DF2<-data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5),AP=c("A1056B","B21056C","C356A","C4BA","D4"),OP=c("AA","BB","AAKLM","DDA","C4AAB"))

  id     AP      OP
  1  A1056B       AA
  2 B21056C       BB
  3   C356A    AAKLM
  4    C4BA      DDA
  5      D4    C4AAB

S<-c("A1","C4")
```

Desired output:

```
   id      AP    OP mut
1  1  A1056B     AA   1
2  2 B21056C     BB   0
3  3   C356A  AAKLM   0
4  4    C4BA    DDA   1
5  5      D4  C4AAB   1
```

I´ve tried:

```
DF2%>%mutate(mut=case_when(grepl(paste0(S, collapse"|"),AP|OP)~1,TRUE~0))
```

But can´t figure how to state multiple columns to search within.

Any ideas?

Best H

Comment: I think I understand what you want to do but is hard with the current example since there are no `S` on any of the elements of any row. I would first clarify this point so the forum can directly answer instead of guessing.

Comment: S<-c("A","C"). As stated in the example

Comment: Sorry I misread!

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
library(dplyr)
DF2 %>% mutate(mut = as.numeric(substring(AP,1,1) %in% S | substring(OP,1,1) %in% S))

  id AP OP mut
1  1 A1 AA   1
2  2 B2 BB   0
3  3 C3 AA   1
4  4 C4 DD   1
5  5 D4 CC   1
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
DF2 %>% pivot_longer(!id, names_to = 'APOP') %>% mutate(n1 = substr(value, 1,1)) %>% 
mutate(mut = case_when(grepl(paste0(S, collapse = '|'), n1) ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0 )) %>% 
group_by(id) %>% summarise(mut = max(mut)) %>% inner_join(DF2)
`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
Joining, by = "id"
# A tibble: 5 x 4
     id   mut AP    OP   
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1     1     1 A1    AA   
2     2     0 B2    BB   
3     3     1 C3    AA   
4     4     1 C4    DD   
5     5     1 D4    CC   
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two base R solution that work very similarly. Basically, use grepl to search the start of strings on the respective columns and check rowwise to see which has a match (using `do.call(pmax, ...)` or `rowSums(...) >= 1`):

```
cols = c("AP", "OP") # I did by name, this works with names, integer, or logical
pattern = paste0("^(", paste0(S, collapse = "|"), ")")

do.call(pmax, lapply(DF2[cols], function(x) grepl(pattern, x)))
[1] 1 0 1 1 1

as.integer(rowSums(sapply(DF2[cols], function(x) grepl(pattern, x))) >= 1)
[1] 1 0 1 1 1
```

Or, within `lapply()`/`sapply()` you could swap out: `grepl(pattern, x)` for `substr(x, 1, 1) %in% S`